# System.Timers Timer not firing event

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I have to start timer on the event when eyes are closed for a certain duration.If timer is elapsed Screen turns Off.If eye open before timer is elapsed timer is stopped and screen turns On.

**ComputationOfTimer(); monitors whether eyes are open/closed. This is working fine as I am getting right feedback in console.**

```
            private void ComputationOfTimer()
        {
            if (blink[0] == 100)        //If eye Closed detected
            {
                ctrlTimerStop = 3;
                ctrlTimerStart = ctrlTimerStart - 1;
                System.Console.Write("\n\t Eyes Closed");                    
                timerStarting();
            }
            else                        //If eyes are open before timer is elapsed 
           //we have to stop timer
            {
                ctrlTimerStart = 5;
                ctrlTimerStop -= 1;
                //System.Console.Write("\n\t\t\t\t\t Opened");
                timerStopping();
            }
        }
```

timerStarting() starts the timer

```
            public void timerStarting()
        {
            if (ctrlTimerStart == 0)
            {

                screenOffTimer.Interval = 3000;
                screenOffTimer.Elapsed += screenOffTimer_Tick_ScreenOff;
                screenOffTimer.AutoReset=false;

                if (!screenOffTimer.Enabled)  //Starts timer only once
                {
                    screenOffTimer.Enabled = true;
                    System.Console.Write("Timer Chaloo Hai");
                }
            }
        }
```

Logic of Screen Off and Sleep

```
            void screenOffTimer_Tick_ScreenOff(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Console.Write("Eyes Closed For long time bro!");
            Beep(440, 1000); // Concert A, for 1 second
            SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_OFF);

    //as eyes are still closed send pc to Sleep start one more timer

            gotoSleepTimer.Interval = 10000;
            gotoSleepTimer.Elapsed += gotoSleepTimer_Tick_SleepOff;
            gotoSleepTimer.AutoReset = false;

            if (!gotoSleepTimer.Enabled)
            {
                gotoSleepTimer.Start();
            }                

        }

        void gotoSleepTimer_Tick_SleepOff(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Console.Write("So rahe hain bhai ab");
            Beep(440, 2000); // Concert A, for 1 second
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, false, false);

        }
```

timerStopping(); to stop the timer if Eyes are opened earlier

```
            public void timerStopping()     //To stop timer when Eyes Open
        {
            if (ctrlTimerStop == 0)
            {
                //to do timer stop logic
                if (screenOffTimer.Enabled)
                {
                    screenOffTimer.Stop();
                    System.Console.Write("Timer Band Ho Gaya");
                }
                //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Timer Stopped");
                SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, MONITOR_ON);

                if (gotoSleepTimer.Enabled)
                {
                    gotoSleepTimer.Stop();
                }
            }

        }
```

**Timer is not firing even after time is elapsed.I tried DispatcherTimer before but that is to update WPF UI and I have different objective.**

Declaration part:

```
System.Timers.Timer screenOffTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
System.Timers.Timer gotoSleepTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

Comment: The timer may very well be running, but as unhandled exceptions are silently ignored by it you may have an exception somewhere in the method which prevents it from completing successfully. Try adding a try/catch inside the timer callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
EventTabTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(gotoSleepTimer_Tick_SleepOff);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked now Screen is turning Off but instead of going to sleep Screen is blinking continuously.Now I have to refine that logic.Thanks again for quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

I could not see `screenOffTimer.Start()` in the code attached in question. May be thats the problem

Thanks

Comment: **screenOffTimer.Enabled = true;** is same as **screenOffTimer.Start()** isn't it.